# Ruby - syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot, fastlane

please help me what am I doing wrong? Im doing telegram notifier via ruby in my Fastfile and gets that problem:

```
[!] Syntax error in your Fastfile on line 175: Fastfile:175: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end
210...ication/json' --data '{"chat_id": "123456789", "media": [{"t...
211...                        ^~~~~~~
212Fastfile:175: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting end
213... --data '{"chat_id": "123456789", "media": [{"type": "photo"...
214...                      ^~~~~~~~~
```

My code:

```
lane :detox do
    images = Dir.glob("folder/*.png")
      images.each do |image|
        puts image
      sh "curl --request POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"chat_id": "123456789", "media": [{"type": "photo", "media": "attach://image"}]'   https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendMediaGroup"
    end
```

Comment: Not the cause of the syntax error, but your JSON is missing a trailing `}`

Comment: @Mwinky: Your code has two `do`, but only one `end`. Also, the argument you pass to your method `sh` is broken. I think it is supposed to be a single string. I suggest that you copy just this string expression and paste it into irb. You will see **many** helpful  error messages. Even when you look at your own posting here at Stackoverflow, you will see from the syntax highlighting of your code, that that string is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few things wrong here. Firstly, you should escape all your quotation marks in the string following `sh`. Otherwise, the string is terminated early and you'll encounter errors.

Secondly, you opened 2 `do` blocks: `lane :detox do` and `images.each do |image|`, but you only have a single `end`.

This should be

```
lane :detox do
    images = Dir.glob("folder/*.png")
    images.each do |image|
      puts image
      sh "curl --request POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{\"chat_id\": \"123456789\", \"media\": [{\"type\": \"photo\", \"media\": \"attach://image\"}]}'   https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendMediaGroup"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is caused by using unescaped double quotes within a double quoted string:

```
str = "foo "bar" baz"
#          ^^^^^ won't work
```

You can escape `"` as `\"` but it's often easier to use a [heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents+-28heredocs-29) instead which doesn't require escaping:

```
sh <<-CMD
  curl https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendMediaGroup \
    --request POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"chat_id": "123456789", "media": [{"type": "photo", "media": "attach://image"}]}'
CMD
```

However, instead of building the command yourself, you can also pass the command options as separate arguments to [`sh`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sh/):

```
sh(
  'curl', 'https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendMediaGroup',
  '--request', 'POST',
  '--header', 'Content-Type: application/json',
  '--data', '{"chat_id": "123456789", "media": [{"type": "photo", "media": "attach://image"}]}'
)
```

Which also allows you to create the JSON from a Ruby hash on the fly:

```
require 'json'

data = {
  chat_id: "123456789",
  media: [{ type: "photo", media: "attach://image" }]
}

sh(
  'curl', 'https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendMediaGroup',
  '--request', 'POST',
  '--header', 'Content-Type: application/json',
  '--data', data.to_json
)
```

Doing so ensures that your JSON is always valid. (syntactically)